# Mercurial built-in template style description

Tags: mercurial, hgrc

I am trying to tune the output of `hg log` by defining my own style. In fact, just adding information to the default style would be perfect. Is there a place where I can get the description of the default styles (default, compact, ...) to write my own?

Comment: [Here](http://selenic.com/hg/help/templates) and [here](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/customizing-the-output-of-mercurial.html) should be very useful, though I didn't see an explicit statement of the defaults.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research, I finally found the location of the default styles for `hg log`, located on my ubuntu 14.04 at

```
/usr/share/mercurial/templates/
```

You can find there the following files:

```
map-cmdline.bisect
map-cmdline.changelog
map-cmdline.compact
map-cmdline.default
map-cmdline.phases
map-cmdline.xml
```

They do not contain any color scheme, but they are allowed me to build my 'patched' version of default.

Answer (score 2):

From other comments elsewhere you can find out where the styles location is by:

```
hg debuginstall --config ui.editor=cat
```

Or using a bug if you choose a directory under the template it complains and tells you where they are (probably should for non matching styles), well it does for 1.9.2:

```
hg in --style paper
```

If you want to colour the output you could use the color extension now.
add to .hgrc:

```
[extensions]
color=
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know how to use the various keywords that Mercurial *templating* feature understands (see `hg help templating` for a very complete usage doc), then you can either:

- specify your choices by giving a template on the command line, e.g.,

  $ hg tip --template "{rev} at {date|isodate}"\n
  882 at 2014-12-17 08:50 +0100
- or edit an ascii file with the same format and use it with the style option, e.g.,

  $ cat ~/mystyle.txt
  changeset = "{rev} at {date|isodate}\n"
  $ hg tip --style ~/mystyle.txt
  882 at 2014-12-17 08:50 +0100

Comment: Thanks for the doc, I'll read it and try to mimic the default template, so I can add my own flavor to it. But I'm still curious to know if this kind of template description for the build-in styles is available somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

It's strange, but the default templates are hardcoded in mercurial code.

The file `map-cmdline.default` is never read at runtime, but can be used to exactly replicate mercurial output (and thus to extend it).

Example of how to extend `hg log` output to include the git commit hash of a git repository cloned via [hg-git](https://hg-git.github.io/).

Look for the location of `map-cmdline.default`:

```
$ hg debuginstall --config ui.editor=cat | grep "default template"
checking default template (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/templates/map-cmdline.default)
```

Edit `/etc/mercurial/hgrc`, pasting a slightly modified version of `map-cmdline.default`:

```
...first part of your hgrc...

[templates]
# support "git-commit" line in hg log
changeset_git = '{cset}{cset_git}{branches}{bookmarks}{tags}{parents}{user}{ldate}{ltroubles}{lobsfate}{summary}\n'
cset_git      = '{if(gitnode, "git-commit:  {label("status.unknown", gitnode|short)}\n")}'

...the rest of 'templates' section of map-cmdline.default...

[templatealias]
...the whole 'templatealias' section of map-cmdline.default...
```

Example output:

```
~/git$ hg log --graph
@    changeset:   54881:d420062ce3d6
|\   git-commit:  6326d2e53311    <-- new line, only appears in git clones
| |  tag:         default/pu
| |  tag:         tip
| |  parent:      54879:31a4c8ccc461
| |  parent:      54880:691b9814f119
| |  user:        Junio C Hamano <gitster@pobox.com>
| |  date:        Sun Mar 25 10:52:08 2018 -0700
| |  summary:     Merge branch 'jh/partial-clone' into pu
```